# Printer freezes when printing certain files

Tags: windows, printer, freeze

I have issues with samsung m2070 printer. Whenever I try to print certain documents like tickets or pictures of documents it's freezing and keeps saying "printing..". At first I couldn't realise that it's only for certain documents so I even bought new printer (same model) and issue persists.

Printer is connected to one pc and then shared across several (same issue with all of them) I have an idea that its because of complex files so played around with several functions like eco printing and etc. Even tried changing image to grayscale and but its the same.

It used to be alright.

P.S. Some times when printing PDFs with text only generated from html same thing happens but rarely.

**Additional info as requested:**

- OS: Windows 7 64 bit
- Connection: one PC is used as server and connected via USB and it's
  shared across other PCs.
- Drivers: Up to date
- Printer firmware: Up to date
- OS updates: Up to date

Just want to point out that I do have IT background and I did all those common steps like trying older drivers, restarting spooling, playing with settings and etc.

Comment: Are the files it struggles with larger in size?

Comment: Not really when I converted image to grayscale its size is 56kb so not particulary.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You have left some details out. 1) What version of Windows are you using? 2) How is the printer connected to the PC? 3) What driver version are you using for the printer (a new one may be available at the manufacturer's website)?

Comment: What type of documents cause the problem (.doc, .docx, .pdf, etc)? Any similarities in the content of the files (images, line-art, etc)?

Comment: I would say it chokes when its printing files in color like tickets, pictures of documents.

Comment: Just got an idea new printer came without cable so I'll try to change that first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by a faulty cable, so not reproducible and not useful for future readers.

Comment: @DavidPostill: I think knowing that weird printer failures may be caused by a bad cable is important information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from comments in OP:

> Turns out to be faulty cable.